# Preserve value of a variable in Ansible when looping through 'include_role'

Tags: ansible

So let's say I have a role in Ansible that takes one input parameter and, at the end of its execution, uses the `set_fact` module to write the output to a variable. Obviously, if I loop through this role with multiple values as input parameters then the value of this output variable will be overwritten with every iteration of the loop.

Without modifying the role (as I'm not allowed to) would it be possible to preserve the output of this role (from the variable) in a list for example?

I've been trying to use `register` to capture the output of this role execution but apparently this doesn't return the expected output as I later found out [here](https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/136).

Any other solutions possible?

Example code:

```
- name: Declare list of input parameters
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    list_of_parameters:
      - 1
      - 2
      - 3
      - 4

- name: Include role
  ansible.builtin.include_role:
    name: my_role
  loop:
    "{{ list_of_parameters }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: item
  vars:
    my_input_var: "{{ item }}"
  register:
    task_output # ideally, I'd like to preserve the value of output variable 'my_output_var' through each iteration of the loop into a list.
```

Comment: You can use `set_fact` with the variable the role produces, surely?

Comment: @RichardHuxton definitely, my issue is doing so when I'm looping through `include_role`. That doesn't seem to be possible?

Comment: you'll need to show a cut-down example then - I can't think of any reason why this wouldn't work.

Comment: @RichardHuxton give me a moment, I'll edit my main post.

Comment: @RichardHuxton done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last I checked you can't loop over a `block` which is a shame. So - you need to put the tasks you want to run in their own file:

```yaml
# looped_tasks.yml
- name: Include role
  ansible.builtin.include_role:
    name: x
- name: add to dict
  set_fact:
    combined: "{{ combined|default({}) | combine( {item: x} ) }}"
```

The above includes a role "x" that sets a variable "x" to "100" (presumably your role does something more useful).

The complex-looking `combined` stuff gets run each time and if the variable isn't set yet, creates a default empty dictionary otherwise it uses the previous value and appends key=loop item, value=x.

Then your playbook has:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Declare list of input parameters
    ansible.builtin.set_fact:
      list_of_parameters:
        - 1
        - 2
        - 3
        - 4
  - name: Include tasks with role
    ansible.builtin.include_tasks:
      file: looped_tasks.yml
    loop:
      "{{ list_of_parameters }}"
  - debug:
      var: combined
```

Which will produce:

```
TASK [debug] ************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "combined": {
        "1": 100,
        "2": 100,
        "3": 100,
        "4": 100
    }
}
```